# Microservice data replication patterns

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, database-replication, event-driven, eventual-consistency

In a microservice architecture, we usually have two ways for 2 microservices to communicate. Let’s say service A needs to get information from service B. The first option is a remote call, usually synchronous over HTTPS, so service A query an API hosted by service B.

The second option is adopting an event-driven architecture, where the state of service B can be published and consumed by service A in an asynchronous way. Using this model, service A can update its own database with the information from the service B’s events and all queries are made locally in this database. This approach has the advantage of a better decoupling of microservices, from development until operations. But it comes with some disadvantages related to data replication.

The first one is the high consumption of disk space, since the same data can reside in the databases of the microservices that need it. But the second one is worst in my opinion: data can become stale if service B can’t process its subscription as fast as needed, or it can’t be available for service A at the same time it’s created at service B, given the eventual consistency of the model.

Let’s say we’re using Kafka as an event hub, and its topics are configured to use 7 days of data retention. Service A is kept in sync as service B publishes its state. After two weeks, a new service C is deployed and its database needs to be enriched with all information that service B holds. We can only get partial information from Kafka topics since the oldest events are gone. My question here is **what are the patterns we can use to achieve this microservice’s database enrichment** (besides asking service B to republish all its current state to the event hub).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 options:

1. You can enable log compaction for Kafka for an individual topic. That will keep the most recent value for a given key discarding old updates. This saves space and also holds more data than the normal mode for a given retention period
2. Assuming you take a backup of service B DB on a daily basis, on introduction of a new service C, you need to first create the initial state of C from the latest backup of B and then replay the Kafka topic events from the particular offset id that represents the data after the backup.

Answer (score 1):

Your concern is right but at the same time Microservices approach is give and take. You get loose coupling at the cost of individual data base for each service. There is no right answer to microservices architecture and really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

According to CAP theorem you have to compromise between consistency and availability and in most cases we go with eventual consistency . If your service A is not consistent with B then it will eventually be and that's the trade off at the cost of availability.

Another thing regarding microservice is that you only keep the reference of data from other service and may be very limited actual data from other service but definitely not much. And that too only if replicating the data is making your service independent and autonomouse,  if you can't achieve any of it even after replicating the data then there is no point. e.g. Your shipping service will have complete history of order transition , but your booking service only have the latest status of order (e.g. in transit , On board etc) . User goes to booking and you show the current status of the order. But if user click details you get all the order transition history from shipping microservice.  Now at some point your shipping service goes down and your user comes to check the status you at-least have current order status even when you can't show the details because order status is replicated in the booking service.

Regarding new services joining the system at later stage , Event sourcing is the pattern that you use for these kind of scenarios. Its complex pattern but it will bring your newly added services to the state at which you want them to be. You basically save all your events in an event store and replay them to attain the current state of the system and pre-populate service C database with those events.